# ARC: __bridge versus __bridge_retained using contextInfo test case

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, retaincount, toll-free-bridging

Consider this ARC code:

```
- (void)main {
    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"s"];
    [NSApp beginSheet:sheet 
           modalForWindow:window 
           modalDelegate:self 
           didEndSelector:@selector(sheetDidEnd:returnCode:context:) 
           contextInfo:(__bridge void *)s
    ];
}

- (void)sheetDidEnd:(NSWindow *)sheet returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode context:(void *)context {
    NSString *s = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)context;
}
```

Question: on line 7, should `__bridge` be used, or `__bridge_retained`, or does it not matter, or does the choice depend on the string's retain count (that is, whether the string is explicitly alloced vs being autoreleased through a class initializer like `+[NSString stringWithString:]`?

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate, but may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12916491/1445366.  (Also, irrelevant to your question: this NSApp method is deprecated in OS X 10.9.)

Comment: It does matter when you choose one over another. If you use bridge_retained then you are responsible for freeing the retained object but if you used __bridge, the ARC will take care of it for you.

Comment: @ldindu: If __bridge_retained is matched by (exactly one) __bridge_transfer, ARC will also "take care" of releasing the object.

Comment: @Martin R agreed with your statement, I am explaining between __bridge and __bridge_retained as asked in the question as the Steveo hasn't mentioned about bridge transfer, so left explaining it.

Comment: Consider using CFBridgingRetain() and CFBridgingRelease() instead of __bridge_retained and __bridge_transfer. They do the same thing, but you may find the CF functions easier to reason about.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally, it is either

```
// Object to void *:
contextInfo:(__bridge void *)s

// void * to object:
NSString *s = (__bridge NSString *)context;
```

or

```
// Object to void *, retaining the object:
contextInfo:(__bridge_retained void *)s

// void * to object, transferring ownership.
// The object is released when s goes out of scope:
NSString *s = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)context;
```

In the first case, there is no transfer of ownership, therefore the main program
**must hold a strong reference** to the object as long as the sheet is active.

In the second case, the object is retained when creating the sheet, and released 
in the `sheetDidEnd:` method. It is not required that the main program holds
a strong reference, so this is the safe method.

Comment: A third case: __bridge_retained or CFBridgingRetain() when setting the context, but plain __bridge cast when using the context. This is used when the context should live forever but there's no other convenient place to store a strong reference to it.