# convert objective-c code to c++

Tags: c++, ios

I constructed my code in objective-c for ios in-app purchasing.
There is one project needs c++ code.
Just wonder if I change iap objective-c code to c++,
is there any special point I need to notice?

Your comment welcome

Comment: You mean besides the fact that Objective-C has a radically different object model, potentially making any "porting" basically a rewrite?

Comment: Do you want to use Objective-C on other platform? Or want to try Objective-C++? You can't use the in-app purchase library on other platform.

Comment: The question would be a bit more specific (less "too broad") if you specified the execution platform.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot use Objective-C objects in C++. But C++ can use Objective-C library with C interface. Objective-C++ can use Objective-C objects in C++ too.

Comment: This is wrong, we have Objective-C++ and can bridge to opaque void pointers.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916491/pass-an-objective-c-object-to-a-function-as-a-void-pointer